# Cannot deserialize value of type `java.math.BigInteger` from String

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a API like below, it receive and process a number that is given by user

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public String test(@Validated @RequestBody InputRequest input) throws Exception {
        return "{\"num\":" + String.valueOf(input.getNum()) +"}";
    }
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class InputRequest{
    private BigInteger num;
}
```

And then my tester sent a string of junk like `"!@#$^!&*"` to `num` field, my API show Http 400 and a line of exception pop up

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.math.BigInteger` from String "!@#$%^&*()_+<>?~!": not a valid representation; ...
```

Is there any way to block such junk input or handle this exception by my own? Without change the data type of `num`?

Comment: What does "block" mean? Your server should respond somehow to the request anyway. It responds with "400 - bad request" which looks appropriate

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off getting rid of that at the client?

Comment: @g00se No, at least not *just* in the client. Always design your API to be resilient to bad actors which are not your own client.

Comment: Well, as @gdomo said, it seems the server is already responding properly

Comment: Well, my tester demand it should show "our error code" for incorrect input parameter, but not `400 - bad request`. sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you see is the expected functionality.

If you want to handle non-number values,
consider changing the handler method to receive a String value and then parse
it yourself.

Here is some sample code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils;

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public String test(@RequestBody String requestBody) throws Exception
{
    String returnValue;
    
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(requestBody)))
    {
        final InputRequest inputRequest;
        
        try
        {
            inputRequest = objectMapper.readValue(requestBody, InputRequest.class);
            
            returnValue = "blam";  // handle success
        }
        catch (some exception type)
        {
            returnValue = "kapow"; // handle parse error.
            // handle parse exceptions here.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = "blam"; // handle no request body here.
    }
    
    return returnValue;
}


// The dependency for commons lang3
//      <dependency>
//        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
//        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
//        <version>3.5</version>
//      </dependency>
```

Comment: this is the simplest way to achieve what I need. thx

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom deserializer to handle invalid value:

```
public class BigIntegerDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<BigInteger> {

    protected BigIntegerDeserializer() {
        super(BigInteger.class);
    }
    @Override
    public BigInteger deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser, final DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        final String input = jsonParser.getText();
        try {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(Long.parseLong(input));
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be a number.");
        }
    }
}
```

Then annotate that deserializer to your field:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class InputRequest {


    @JsonDeserialize(using = BigIntegerDeserializer.class) // Here
    private BigInteger num;
}
```

In case you want to return the message "Value must a number" back to tester. You can handle the exception using ExceptionHandler:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public static ResponseEntity<String> handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(
        @NonNull final HttpMessageNotReadableException exception
    ) {
        // Since Jackson wrap your IllegalArgumentException exception before throwing. You have to find the cause exception inside it.
        Throwable rootCause = org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(exception);
        final String message = rootCause.getMessage(); // Value must be a number.
        return ...;
    }
```

Comment: infomative, but doesn't seem like I could reply our own error code and msg and say your input is not a number to the client with your deserialize function?

Comment: @Kaninchen, I edited the answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hmm, that made the complexity for code maintainence increased. I think parsing it from string using object mapper would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Validation of request body can be done using Validation
For example - https://blog.tericcabrel.com/validate-request-body-and-parameter-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define an [@ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotated method in your controller:

```java
@ExceptionHandler
ResponseEntity<String> handleMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
  // change the status below according to requirements
  return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}
```

For handling exceptions globally use [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html), for more details about exception handling check [the blog post](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-exception-handling/).